# Creating a network of objects from custom XML config with Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have a custom XML config defining a kind of network like this

```
S1 ---- O1 ---- O2 ---- O3 ---- T1
 \
   +--- O4 ---- O5 ------------ T2
    \
S2---+- O6 --+- O7 ------------ T4
    /       /
S3-+       /
          /
S4 ------+
```

Where

- `S` is some kind of data source, like a web socket
- `O` is an operator processing the data
- `T` is the target or data sink

These elements are represented with xml blocks like this:

```
<source name="S1" address="ws://example/1" type="websocket" dataType="double" />

<operator name="O6" type="threshold">
    <input name="S1"/>
    <input name="S2"/>
    <input name="S3"/>
    <property name="threshold" value="10.34" />
    <property name="window" value="10.0" />
</operator>

<sink name="T1" type="database">
    <input name="O3"/>
</sink>
```

The dependencies are constructor parameters. My example operator `O6` would have a constructor like this:

```
class ThresholdOperator extends Operator<Boolean> {

    public ThresholdOperator(
        String name,              // "O6"
        List<DataSource> sources, // [S1, S2, S3]
        double threshold,         // 10.34
        double window) {          // 10.0
    ...
```

There could be multiple instances of this class with different constructor parameters. It is possible that a class has more than one constructor. The type parameter of the base class is the output type.

The `type` attribute determines what concrete class has to be instantiated. The `dataType` attribute of the source decides which kind of converter (here `String` to `Double`) should be injected.

To create the instances I need to figurare out a dependency graph and start instantiating the objects without other objects from my graph as dependency (the sources in this case), then I would create the objects which depend only on objects created in the first step and so on.

So I would basically reinvent something like Spring for my special use case. Is there a way to leverage Spring to create and wire objects in my case? A somewhat crude hack would be to transform my xml config to a beans.xml. But maybe there is a better way using `BeanFactory` or the like. Or would it be possible to create the Spring meta-model directly?

I'm using Spring 4.3 but the RC of Spring 5 could be an option, if it would help.

Comment: I've added another possible solution that might be useful for your case. Check out update on my post.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [tag:apache-camel] as you seem to construct some processing routes and instructions for certain endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on [StaticApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/StaticApplicationContext.html). It is stated in the docs that it is:

> Mainly useful for testing.

... but it is a full fledged application context that has support for programmatic bean registration.

You can read your domain-specific xml and define beans based on it inside `StaticApplicationContext`.

[This blog post](http://blog.anvard.org/articles/2013/11/10/spring-static-context.html) can give you an idea on how to use `StaticApplicationContext` to define beans with references and constructor args.

Comment: Thanks, `StaticApplicationContext` was what I was looking for. I suggest that you split your answer (`StaticApplicationContext`, XSLT) to make clear what the selected solution is and to giver others the chance to vote for both approaches separately.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative not yet mentioned here is using [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT).

The idea is to define `xsl` that maps your domain-specific `xml` to spring beans `xml` ([XSLT](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp)+[XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) should be more than enough to cover your case).

You can then read domain-specific `xml`, [transform](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer-javax.xml.transform.Source-) it with that `xsl` and feed the result to spring.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach to instantiate your objects from the document would be to either

1. create an XML Schema describing your data format and using JAXB to create your Java classes
2. annotate your existing Java classes with JAXB annotations

Comment: I'm already using JAXB, but the resulting object structure is too far away from my target objects and I can not get much closer due to limitations of JAXB. So I need an additional assembly step, but I like your idea anyway since it could be the solution in simpler cases.

Comment: Have you considered using XSLT or mapstruct to transform the input to what you need?

Answer (score 1):

The "crud" hack approach may be a better approach but instead of converting your config xml to beans xml file manually, I suggest you to look at the [Extensible XML authoring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html) approach.

The configuration parser, a.k.a. bean definition parser, allows you to build the bean definitions which will eventually be used your application's spring context to instantiate the beans.

This should also eliminate the needs of figuring out the dependency hierarchy  manually and instantiation of objects yourself.

Hope it answer your question.

Comment: This is a really nice approach. However, if I understand it correctly, one woule still need usual Spring XML as a "container". So I wouldn't be able to use the externe XML file as is, but could convert it easily to my custom Spring XML extension format. Right?